# how to sort a list(that used hashtable for lookup items)

Tags: c#

this is my code .I want to sort listbox based Name & display thems on listbox.
I use Hashtable class for search between Items.So now i don't Konw how can i sort my list!!!
i create a class with name: Customer,and use it in my code!
thanks so much for any help:-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace Structure_Demo
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Form level members.
    public Hashtable objCustomers = new Hashtable();
    public ArrayList objCustomer = new ArrayList();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get
        { 
            //Return the selected customer
            return (Customer)lstCustomers.Items[lstCustomers.SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
    private void DisplayCustomer(Customer objCustomer)
    { 
        //Display the customer detils in the form
        txtName.Text = objCustomer.Name;
        txtFirstName.Text = objCustomer.FirstName;
        txtLastName.Text = objCustomer.LastName;
        txtEmail.Text = objCustomer.Email;
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create some customers 
        CreateCustomer("cuser 1", "customer 1", "cu.customer1@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("auser 2", "customer 2", "au.customer2@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("buser 3", "customer 3", "bu.customer3@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("guser 4", "customer 4", "gu.customer4@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("euser 5", "customer 5", "eu.customer5@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("huser 6", "customer 6", "hu.customer6@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("duser 7", "customer 7", "du.customer7@ssamail.com");
        CreateCustomer("fuser 8", "customer 8", "fu.customer8@ssamail.com");
    }
    public void CreateCustomer(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email)
    { 
        //Declare a customer object.
        Customer objNewCustomer;
        //Create new customer.
        objNewCustomer.FirstName = FirstName;
        objNewCustomer.LastName = LastName;
        objNewCustomer.Email = Email;
        //check if customer isn't currctly in the list
        if (objCustomers.Contains(Email.ToLower()) == false)
        {
            //Add new customer to the list
            objCustomers.Add(Email.ToLower(), objNewCustomer);
            //Add new customer to the listbox control
            lstCustomers.Items.Add(objNewCustomer);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The customer :" + FirstName + LastName + " currently exit", "Structure Demo");
        }

    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if no customer is selected if form list boe then...
        if (lstCustomers.SelectedIndex == -1)
        { 
            //Display a message
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a customer to delete!","Structure Demo");
            //Exit the method
            return;
        }
        //promt the user to delete the selected customer
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete the " + SelectedCustomer.Name + "?", "Structure Demo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        { 
            //Get the customer to be deleted
            Customer objCustomerToDelete = SelectedCustomer;
            //remove the customer from Arraylist
            objCustomers.Remove(txtEmail.Text.ToLower());
            //remove the customer from the list box
            lstCustomers.Items.Remove(objCustomerToDelete);

        }

    }

    private void btnLookup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if customer found in hashtable
        if (objCustomers.Contains(txtEmail.Text.ToLower()) == true)

            //Display the customer name
            MessageBox.Show("The customer name is: " + ((Customer)objCustomers[txtEmail.Text.ToLower()]).Name, "Structure Demo");
            else
            //Display an error message
             MessageBox.Show("The customer with email address: " + txtEmail.Text + " does not exit!", "Structure Demo");

    }

    private void lstCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Display the customer details 
        DisplayCustomer(SelectedCustomer);
    }

    private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //

    }
```

Comment: I can't believe your code even compiles. What is `lstCustomers`? Where is it declared?

Comment: This is a partial class from a winforms app - the UI controls are likely declared in generated code in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly sort a HashTable but you can use a SortedDictionary as an alternative or maintain a list of the HashTable keys the sorted order that you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I really don't know how can i do it:-/this is my first winform app and i need your guidance